# Php input range value doesn't change

Tags: php, html

got some weird thing with **html input range** displaying it's value on handler.

got some html/php code :

```
    <div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" style="-webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow,  green);
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;" 
min="1" max="<?php printf(number_format($buy_now_price, 2, '', ''),
 $currency_code_display); ?>" 
value="<?php echo number_format($result->bid, 2, '', '') . " " . $currency_code_display; ?>"
 class="slider" id="myRange">
                    </div>
```

The thing is that this code shows min max and value of the input , but the handler always is on the middle. Why ?

Here is some photos : 
 [image]

**All of the inputs got different value , but the handlers are all the same ? What to do ?**

Comment: You only don't know where do I get value and max , but you don't need to know how I get them. All other code is here, my input range and I show that those value and max are wrote in my inputs , all different, but  in the final the handler doesn't really show different values. I want to know why this could happen.

Comment: 2000000 and 130000 shouldnt be 50% like it shows.

Comment: Using Developer tools, try experimenting with different values. It looks like `value` has a trailing space: start by removing that. Then try using decimal values (e.g: `.65`) to see if your slider is expecting a percentage rather than a raw value.

Comment: input type range shouws automatically value and moves handler by it's value ? isnt it ? https://jsfiddle.net/w6fc14nk/

Comment: Tryed changing , the value isn't changing on handler.

Comment: then why he is not showing the symbol ? I deleted it, it was , but not now as you can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you are printing this in the input's *value*:

```
<?php echo number_format($result->bid, 2, '', '') . " " . $currency_code_display; ?>
```

In the example that you show, the end result looks something like this:

```
value="1300 "
           ^
```

The trailing space is causing the slider to fall back to its default value (50%). The currency display is irrelevant here: HTML doesn't know what to do with `1300 $` versus `1300 €`.

In short, just use the number. No trailing spaces, no currency markers.